# Maximum number of recursions lower than $RecursionLimit

Tags: recursion

Consider the following code segment:

```
f[x_]:=Module[{y},
   Print[counter++];
   Return[f[x+1]];
];
$RecursionLimit=20;
counter=0;
f[0]
```

The function terminates after only 8 recursions. Now, delete y from the function:

```
g[x_]:=Module[{},
   Print[counter++];
   Return[g[x+1]];
];
$RecursionLimit=20;
counter=0;
g[0]
```

and termination is achieved after 17 recursions. What is the resason for this discrepancy and even in the second case, where are the missing recusions?

My Mathematica version is 10.0.2.0.

Comment: For what it's worth, in version 9, the second one also terminates after 8 recursions.

Comment: Can I give this question a bug tag?